# How to swap first and last letter case in each word after using reverse() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, uppercase, lowercase

I wanna try swapping cases for the first and last letters in each word that are already reversed using the reverse function.

Let's say I have a string like this.

> I am Firdaus

And I wanna make it just like this.

> I ma Suadrif

Here is how the script looks like

```js
let reverseWords = str => {
    console.log(`Input: ${str}`)
    let words = str.split(" ").map(word => {
        let chars = word.split("").reverse();
        let result = chars.map((char, index) => {
            if (index == chars.length-1 && chars.length != 0 && char == char.toUpperCase() && index != 0) {
                return char.toLowerCase();
            }
            return char;
        });
        return result.join('');
    });
    return words.join(' ');
}
console.log(`Output: ${reverseWords("I am Firdaus")}`);
```

If you run the code above, the result is not like what I expected

The uppercase **F** successfully becomes lowercase **f**, but the lowercase **s** failed to become uppercase **S**. I am confused about how to swap the **s** become an uppercase **S**.

Is there a way and the best way to make the string just like what I expected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have logic for `index == chars.length-1`. Similarly you need another `else if` block for `index == 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It look like you need to compare against the *original* string's casing to determine whether the returned character should be upper-cased or lower-cased. Use the index of the (reversed) character you're mapping over to access the original character at the same index in the original word.

```js
const reverseWords = str => str
    .split(' ')
    .map(word => [...word].reverse()
        .map((char, i) => (
            word[i].toLowerCase() === word[i]
            ? char.toLowerCase()
            : char.toUpperCase()
        ))
        .join('')
    )
    .join(' ');
console.log(`Output: ${reverseWords("I am Firdaus")}`);
```

Comment: It works perfectly, bro. Thank you
But I am a bit confused about this
I just change one of the letters in the middle of the word to become an uppercase letter, and it's not changing the case at all. For example, I change Firdaus to FirDaus, and the result is SirDauf. The D does not become d.
Can you @CertainPerformance explain to me bro, why it's happened? while the first and the last letter changed

Comment: From your question, it looked to me like you wanted to preserve the casing *at a particular position* in the original word. Is that right? That's what the code above does. If the middle letter starts out upper-cased, it will be upper-cased in the reversed word as well. If the first letter starts out capitalized, the reversed first letter will become capitalized due to the index casing check.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I mean. And after a few minutes, I read and analyzed your code slowly, I finally got what you mean. I never thought to compare the original string's casing, I just thought to check the casing of the first letter that has changed to the last letter. Hmmm, I have to learn and exercise my logic more than before. Anw, I  thank you for your time and your answer, I really appreciate it